# Invalid quantifier when using an object property to construct a regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to dynamically construct a simple regex from an object property.

```
var type = 'bold';

var styles = {
    "bold italic" : "***",
    "bold"        : "**",
    "italic"      : "*"
};

var re = new RegExp(styles[type], 'g');
```

However, I get an **invalid quantifier** error returned.

If I put the variable in quotes, like so:

```
var re = new RegExp('"' + styles[type] + '"', "g");
```

It works fine when `type == 'italic'` but not `'bold'`

Can anyone explain why this is so, and also offer a fix?

Comment: You don't explain what you expect from the regex your are trying to build.

Comment: The result was largely irrelevant to the question.  I was mostly concerned with the reason an error was being thrown.  It was simply down to a need to escape the '*' as answered by @acdcjunior

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In regexes, the char [`*` is a quantifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html). The expression:

```
a*
```

Means `a` **zero or more times** (`a` could also be an expression).

As you are trying to match the `*` itself and not use it as a quantifier, you should escape it:

```
var styles = {
    "bold italic" : "\\*\\*\\*",
    "bold"        : "\\*\\*",
    "italic"      : "\\*"
};
```

Comment: How stupid of me.... Of course.  Thanks for the super prompt answer.  I will award it to you as soon as I am able.  Cheers

Comment: @user2616246 I believe you should be able to accept acdcjunior's answer, but you can't upvote it, I'll do it for you.